# py-me throws Unpermitted modules Exception for importing itertools

Tags: python, importerror, python-itertools

Am trying to compress a list using py-me but I get an **Unpermitted modules Exception**.

Here is my code:

```
def compress(li):
    from itertools import zip_longest
    return([i for i,j in zip_longest(li,li[1:]) if i!=j])

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,9]

print(compress(x))
```

Py-me gave the following as response.

> OUTPUT : Code was not executed due to Unpermitted Modules Exception
> EXCEPTION : Unpermitted Modules Exception : fromitertoolszip_longest <-^--- modules are not allowed to
> be used in py-me. Check documentation for permitted modules !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is py-me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [py-me documentation](https://github.com/SayadPervez/py-me/blob/main/README.md#unpermitted-modules-exception-), it seems that you cannot use **`from`** keyword or **`. (dot operator)`** in the import section.

Instead of **`from itertools import zip_longest`**, try using  **`import itertools`** and while calling the function, use  **`itertools.zip_longest`**.

The modified code looks something like this :

```
def compress(li):
    import itertools
    return([i for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(li,li[1:]) if i!=j])

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,9]

print(compress(x))
```

If you wanna check a python snippet will run successfully in py-me API, try executing the snippet in [py-me web editor](https://py-me.herokuapp.com/) first and modify the code accordingly.